# in place title editing in IKImageBrowserView

Tags: cocoa, editor, ikimagebrowserview

I am trying to create an in place ttle editing in an IKImageBrowser like the one we have in the finder to rename a file or folder.
Unfortunately I do not have any idea on how to start.

If you have piece of code, pointers, ideas, they are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to subclass IKImageBrowserCell and make your own cells for the IKImageBrowserView.  When the user clicks on the title you'll want to Add a NSTextField subview using with titleFrame dimensions and let them edit that.  Make the cell get the edit did end notification or delegate message (forget which) so you can then grab the string, remove the NSTextField and change the title and cause the cell to redraw.  Something along those lines is where I'd start.